# IPython notebook 2.3.0 on Fedora 21 cannot find FontAwesome

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Looking for help trying to tell IPython notebook where to find the fontawesome fonts on Fedora 21. They are apparently packaged separately under `/usr/share/font-awesome-web`. Is there some configuration for this? Failure to find/serve the font is causing the buttons not to render correctly in the browser...

In the browser, I'm getting a 404:

```
[02:50:16.296] downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "FontAwesome" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147746065 
source: http://192.168.56.88/static/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0 @ http://192.168.56.88/static/style/style.min.css?v=84c99f996b473c651c7a92702ce5cd33
```

And in the terminal where I'm running the notebook server, there's really not much more information:

```
2015-02-26 02:03:32.999 [NotebookApp] Kernel args: {'extra_arguments': [u'--log-level=DEBUG', u"--IPKernelApp.parent_appname='ipython-notebook'", u'--profile-dir', u'/root/.ipython/profile_nb'], 'cwd': u'/home/fedora'}
DEBUG:tornado.access:201 POST /api/sessions (192.168.55.242) 16.53ms
DEBUG:tornado.access:304 GET /api/notebooks/Untitled0.ipynb/checkpoints (192.168.55.242) 24.65ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0 (192.168.55.242) 0.63ms referer=http://192.168.56.88/static/style/style.min.css?v=84c99f996b473c651c7a92702ce5cd33
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.1.0 (192.168.55.242) 0.69ms referer=http://192.168.56.88/static/style/style.min.css?v=84c99f996b473c651c7a92702ce5cd33
```

Comment: If you've installed IPython from the Fedora repos, the packagers should have made sure it can find Fontawesome. If you've installed it separately (e.g. with pip), it should include its own copy of Fontawesome.

Comment: I installed via the repos. Added a query to a closed bug concerning fontawesome, as they said to report further trouble there: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1110646

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just run into this problem myself today. The file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/static/style/style.min.css of the python-ipython-notebook-2.3.0-1.fc21.noarch package has wrong references to font awesome files. A quick and dirty fix is:

cd /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/static
sudo ln -s components/font-awesome/font fonts

It would be best to signal with bug of the python-ipython-notebook in RedHat bugzilla, I will do that if I get some spare time.

Comment: Worked for me! I will leave you to enter a new bug for the correct package on bugzilla, since you conquered this issue. If you'd rather have me do it, let me know. :)